# Change Read-Only (even Admin) permission on Removable Hard Disk Drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, permissions

So basically, I made a goof-up and removed all permissions except Read-Only on my external HDD. Somehow Windows 10 allowed me to remove the permissions for the Administrator also.

Now the HDD is all Read-Only and I am unable to do anything on it, except read from it.

Is there some way I can revert the permissions on the Disk and all its folders/files?

Comment: What is the filesystem on the external drive. It doesn't sound like fat or NTFS.

Comment: If the drive is formatted with NTFS, you need to take ownership of all files, after that you can set permissions even if you don't have any existing rights.

Comment: The file system on the disk is NTFS, it is a Toshiba 2TB External HDD. The error message I get while trying to change permissions is: "Failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied". How do I change the ownership? Not sure on it, as I can see only change permissions in the Properties tab.

Comment: Found the ownership (advanced button, and then in the new dialog box, on the top, it says Owner and Change), it is assigned to Administrator, should I change it to my user and then try to change the permissions again?